# How to save empty pyspark dataframe with header into csv file?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark-pandas

Hi I have dataframe which is having only columns. There is no data for columns. But I am trying to save into file, no header is saving. File is totally blank.

Example:

df.show()

```
+-----+----------------------+-------+---------------------+------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+---------------+------------------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------+------+--------+----------------+----------------------+--------------+-----+-------+---------+------+--------+
|owner|account_priority_score|account|call_objective_clm_id|call_objective_from_date|call_objective_on_by_default|call_objective_record_type|call_objective_to_date|display_dismiss|display_mark_as_complete|display_score|email_template_id|email_template_vault_id|email_template|expiration_date|no_homepage|planned_call_date|posted_date|reason|priority|record_type_name|suggestion_external_id|supress_reason|title|product|survey_id|groups|insrt_dt|
+-----+----------------------+-------+---------------------+------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+---------------+------------------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------+------+--------+----------------+----------------------+--------------+-----+-------+---------+------+--------+
+-----+----------------------+-------+---------------------+------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+----------------------+---------------+------------------------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------+------+--------+----------------+----------------------+--------------+-----+-------+---------+------+--------+
```

But while saving into file headers are not coming.
I am using below code-

```
df.coalesce(1).write.mode('overwrite').csv(output_path, sep=output_delimiter,quote='',escape='\"', header='True', nullValue=None)
```

Comment: Not reproducible

Comment: What is the rationale behind creating empty file with just headers ?

Comment: Rationale is that you may have a process wich does something regularly, but that process does not always generate an output. However, we would still like to know that the process ran. Hence an empty CSV file for example on some landing container provides us that information.

Answer (score 0):

To save an empty PySpark DataFrame with a header into a CSV file, you can follow the below steps:

1. Create an empty PySpark DataFrame with the desired schema and header using createDataFrame method:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType

schema = StructType([StructField("name", StringType(), True), StructField("age", IntegerType(), True)])

df = spark.createDataFrame([], schema)
```

2. Write the DataFrame to a CSV file using the write method with the header option set to True:

```py
df.write.option("header", "true").csv("path/to/save/csv/file")
```

This will create a CSV file with the header and the schema defined in the StructType object, but with no data in it.

Comment: Tried this one but it writes an empty CSV file without anything inside, any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

To do what you are asking you will have to define a schema.

So for example:

```
schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("firstname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("middlename",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("lastname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("id", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("gender", StringType(), True), \
    StructField("salary", IntegerType(), True) \
  ])

df = spark.createDataFrame([],schema=schema)
df.coalesce(1).write.csv("/tmp/csv_data/", header=True)
```

this will output single csv file with just the headers.